# Custom filter overrides original data or causes infinite $digest loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

## Initial Situation

***TL;DR***
*I want to filter a nested array with a custom AngularJS filter. Unfortunately not only the data for ng-repeat are filtered but the original object from $scope too.*

I have a small **demo** as a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/7XRB2/
E.g. search for `Test` and the list will getting shorter. Delete your search and you'll see what happens: nothing. The filter don't filters *the list*, he filters *the original data*!

This is my filter:

```
app.filter('searchFilter', function() {
  return function(areas, searchTerm) {
    if (!angular.isUndefined(areas)
      && !angular.isUndefined(searchTerm)) {

      var searchExp;
      searchExp = new RegExp(searchTerm, 'gi');

      var tmpAreas = [];
      angular.forEach(areas, function(area) {
        var tmpTopics = [];
        angular.forEach(area.topics, function(topic) {
          var tmpVideos = [];
          angular.forEach(topic.videos, function(video) {
            if (video.title.match(searchExp)) {
              tmpVideos.push(video);
            }
          });
          topic.videos = tmpVideos;
          if (topic.videos.length > 0 || topic.title.match(searchExp)) {
            tmpTopics.push(topic);
          }
        });
        area.topics = tmpTopics;
        if (area.topics.length > 0) {
          tmpAreas.push(area);
        }
      });
      return tmpAreas;
    }
    else {
      return areas;
    }
  }
});
```

I already implemented another custom search filter that works great and doesn't have this issue:

```
app.filter('mainNavigationFilter', function () {
  return function (elements, selectedElement) {
    if (!angular.isUndefined(elements) && !angular.isUndefined(selectedElement) && selectedElement.length > 0) {
      var tempElements = [];
      angular.forEach(selectedElement, function (id) {
        angular.forEach(elements, function (element) {
          if(angular.equals(element.id, id)
            tempElements.push(element);
          }
        });
      });
      return tempElements;
    }
    else {
      elements
    }
  }
});
```

## What I think is the problem

I'm using `topic.videos = tmpVideos;` and `area.topics = tmpTopics;` in my filter. I guess, that due to javascripts object reference these new assignments are inherited to the original object - my scope object.

After some research I found `angular.copy()` and added following block in my filter:

```
var cpAreas;
cpAreas = angular.copy(areas);
```

In addition I changed the first `angular.forEach` to

```
angular.foreach(cpAreas, function(area) {[...]});
```

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dTA9k/

### Infinite $digest loop

Yippi! The filter works as expected - unless you open the console ...
Now the filter causes a new problem:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [...]
```

I found a few questions on SO about this error and it looks like it's thrown because the filter is returning a new object each time due to `angular.copy`.

**Any ideas how I can solve this problem?**

Comment: Your second example doesn't seem to work (with chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a custom ng-repeat.

So i tried your code and use $index instead. For topic.title and video.title, I don't know. Try a custom ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-app="videoList">
    <input ng-model='search' />
    <ul ng-controller='AreasController' class="video-list-areas">
        <li ng-repeat='area in filtered = (subject.areas | searchFilter:search)'>
            {{subject.areas[$index].title}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat='topic in area.topics'>
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat='video in topic.videos'>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Your filter works, I tried having just this in your HTML:

```
<div ng-app="videoList">
    <input ng-model='search' />
    <ul ng-controller='AreasController' class="video-list-areas">

        {{subject.areas | searchFilter:search}}


    </ul>
</div>
```